# Derived class initialisation order

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently working my way through the Kotlin docs for this section where they cover [Derived class initialization order](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order).

For the following snippet...

```
open class Base(val name: String) {

  init { println("Initializing Base") }

  open val size: Int = name.length.also { println("Initializing size in Base: $it") }
}

class Derived(
    name: String,
    val lastName: String
  ) : Base(name.capitalize().also { println("Argument for Base: $it") }) {

  init { println("Initializing Derived") }

  override val size: Int =
    (super.size + lastName.length).also { println("Initializing size in Derived: $it") }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println("Constructing Derived(\"hello\", \"world\")")
  val d = Derived("hello", "world")
}
```

when executed it prints this:

`Constructing Derived("hello", "world")
Argument for Base: Hello
Initializing Base
Initializing size in Base: 5
Initializing Derived
Initializing size in Derived: 10`

My question is, why when `override val size: Int = (super.size + lastName.length).also { println("Initializing size in Derived: $it") }`
is executed does it not print `Initializing size in Base: 5` again?

I would have thought it would print something like this:

`Constructing Derived("hello", "world")
Argument for Base: Hello
Initializing Base
Initializing size in Base: 5
Initializing Derived
Initializing size in Base: 5 // Print because .also is called again ?
Initializing size in Derived: 10`

Comment: A read-only property is only initialised once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing `Base` only once.
For that reason you're also initialising `size` only once.
For that reason you'll execute your `also` block only once.

Or, to answer your question in a different manner, it doesn't print `Initializing size in Base` second time, because it doesn't executes `name.length.also { println("Initializing size in Base: $it") }` second time.